# django authentication model - login with emailed link?

Tags: python, django, authentication

Is there a way to set up the django authentication model where, instead of a password, users put in their email address, and then are emailed a link that they click on to login with? If so, are there any tutorials on how to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Yes, there is.

You'll either need to hope there is already a module out for this, otherwise you will have to write your own way of authenticating.

###### I'll give a rough estimate of how it's gonna work.

- First, you will need to create a `class` inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`
- Set the username field to email, still include password fields. They are required.
- Then, you will need to create a manager for that custom base user.
- the user manager must have two methods: `create_user()` and `create_superuser()`
- Then, in a view, have user enter their email address, and then generate a token with Django's `default_token_generator`, and send that token via e-mail to the user.
- Create a view which accepts the token, and logs the user in.

#### I highly advise you to take the docs as your guide. This might get relatively complicated.

[More info on the Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/)

> Side note: This will not be as secure as email and password validation. If a user's email gets hacked, the hackers will instantly know not only which site they can target, but also get a free pass to access.

Alternatively; check out Django AllAuth, they provide lots of ways to authenticate, including with Gmail or Facebook. There are some great tutorials online, but you'll have to do some googling. ;)

Comment: That lib might help as well: https://github.com/aaugustin/django-sesame